# PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, permission-denied, shutil

```py
import shutil

def create_dir(path):
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.mkdir(path)
    else:
        shutil.rmtree(path)
```

when I run this code it gives me permission error, even though I have access to that directory.

Also, I use Windows and I have tried running as administrator

Comment: Which line is throwing that error? [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Having access to one resource doesn't mean you're allowed to do anything you want with it.

Answer (score 1):

Try with ignore_errors=True,

```
import shutil

def create_dir(path):
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.mkdir(path)
    else:
        shutil.rmtree(path, ignore_errors = True)
```

Comment: Thanks, ignore_error works. But wanted to ask does it cause any problems like file corruption or something

Comment: It wont cause any problem, if the case is to delete the entire directory, 
But beware of using this kind of delete without check anything, because you will lose all the files, which you can't retrieve.

Comment: This only ignore_errors, it does not force deletion of the files

Answer (score 0):

Check if the folder is not Read-Only.

Or you can also run command:

```
import os
os.system('whoami')
```

It will show you which user is currently **registered as launching user**.